# Moving background gradient in diagonal

Tags: css

I want to reproduce this effect http://jsfiddle.net/X78qN/199/ diagonally, i try it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/X78qN/227/

So, my container div is already rotated and now i search how to perform diagonally the effect, for having it left to the right, how to do it ?

When i try `background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, ...);` , it's not rotated and i try to play with positions, but result is not that i expected

Comment: I don't see any effect on your first [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X78qN/199/).

Comment: Perhaps it's because there is some code only for chrome and you don't have it ? the effect is a white halo moved left to the right, with yellow background.

Comment: Well, yea I know that. I tried on FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: Why not just use `transform: matrix(....)`? If you want, I can create an example.

Comment: Yes, because i'm not very familiar to this

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following styles to bar

```
.bar {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: -40px;
```

and i think that now it works

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X78qN/250/)